# Bijective function in sml

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I would like to define a function that takes an integer n and returns an integer n* such that n and n* are in the same set of integers from 1 to n,and the function must be bijective.

I tried the following

```
fun bij(n) =
      let 
        val ls = zip(upto (1, n), List.rev(upto (1, n))) 
        val Tw_2 = fn(a, b) => b
      in Tw_2(List.last(ls, n-1)) end;
```

but unfortunately, it returns 1 for all my values of n. I am really stuck here.
Can anyone give me some ideas on how to implement this?

The behavior of `bij` must look something like

```
bij(1) = 3
bij(2) = 2
bij(3) = 1
```

Comment: Do you possibly want to define a function that takes an integer n and returns a function that takes an integer m and returns an integer m* such that m and m* are in the same set of integers from 1 to n?

Comment: I don't get it, in your first example n=1, and n*=3. So how is it that n and n* are in the same set of integers from 1 to n? For sure n* should be an integer between 1 and n. Could you please elaborare?

Comment: well maybe i failed to explain what i really want,the big picture is like this:I have a list '[2,1,3]',i would want a function that permutes this list back to '[1,2,3]' for example.

Comment: Something's missing there... You want `bij(1)` to return a value between `1` and `n`, but you haven't told it what `n` is. It needs another parameter.

Comment: In the code above is `zip` actually `ListPair.zip`? And what is the definition of `upto`? Furthermore, `List.last` only takes a single argument, which function did you actually mean? Do you just need an arbitrary function that satisfies your specification (the simplest one that comes to mind is `fn x => x` ;)) or a specific one? In your example it looks as if for given `n`, `bij(n, i)` should map the numbers `1 2 3 ... n` (in this order) to `n n-1 n-2 ... 1` (in this order)? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, an easy solution would be:

```
fun bij(n, i) = n + 1 - i;
```

Which can be represented by the following table

```
i         | 1    2    3  ... n-2  n-1  n
bij(n, i) | n  n-1  n-2  ...   3    2  1
```

and which works as expected for numbers between `1` and `n`. Intuitively a (positive) number `i` is `i` steps "to the right of `0`" and we map this to a number that is `i` (actually `i - 1`) steps "to the left of `n`".

Maybe you wanted to construct the above table explicitly via lists?

```
fun upto(m, n) = if n < m then [] else m :: upto(m+1, n);

fun table n = ListPair.zip (upto(1, n), List.rev (upto(1, n)));
```

**Example:**

```
> table 5;
val it = [(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)]: (int * int) list
```

Then to get the `i`-th pair of a list `xs` you could use

```
List.nth (xs, i-1)
```

Putting all together

```
fun bij(n, i) =
      let
        val table = ListPair.zip (upto(1, n), List.rev (upto(1, n)));
        fun snd(x, y) = y;
      in snd(List.nth (table, i-1)) end;
```

Which does the same as the initial function, except in a more complicated way.